# Is there any other alternative treatment in his case?

Tags: cracked-broken-tooth

My 14-year-old son while playing soccer fell down and lost one of his teeth. His friends rushed him to a nearby emergency dental care in Toronto.

His dentist told him that if the knocked out tooth could be replaced back into the socket within 30 minutes, the chances of tooth surviving is high. But in a hurry, they forgot to take the knocked out tooth.

Is there any other alternative treatment in his case?

Comment: Did they genuinely forget the tooth?  Probably the best treatment would be to educate them on first aid and the importance of procedures for medical emergencies.  Chalk it up as a life lesson, as to knowing when a few seconds assessing a situation can be spared.  As for the tooth, the 30 minute limit is probably for optimal recovery.  How the tooth was stored in the interim, and at what temperature, is also a factor.  I seem to remember that the pulp becomes unsafe for use if it is away from the body for more than an hour.

Comment: If your question is whether there's something that can be done for him, there are tooth bridge options, implants, and other things - the dentist should be the one to recommend what is best for him.